# What is the purpose of the Common Files folder in Program Files?

Tags: windows

Most Windows computers have a Common Files folder inside of Program Files. What is its purpose?

Comment: And who creates it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s2esdf4x%28v=vs.100%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396):

> **Common Files Folder** A folder for components that are shared across applications. Typically C:\Program Files\Common.
>
> **Common Files Folder (64-bit)** Same as the Common Files Folder, but for use only with 64-bit installers.

A slightly different definition is provided in the book [Microsoft Windows XP Power Pack by Stu Sjouwerman](http://www.quepublishing.com/articles/article.aspx?p=101731), published Apr 4, 2003:

> The Program Files folder is home to 16 subfolders:
>
> - **Common Files**. This folder contains files shared with the Microsoft applications [sic].

I feel that folder exists mostly because MS wanted a place for its own libs shared among many programs - although it doesn't seem to get used by MS very much either!

In practice, few applications use it.

Maybe it is a requirement for an application desiring to obtain a "Designed for XP/Vista/nnn" logo(?) that it should use that folder to store files that are common within the application (this is *speculation* on my part - so don't take my word for it!).

Answer (score 0):

The "Common Files" folder holds common folders and files of different apps. These files are shared files so that other apps/programs can use these files and their functions. The majority of the programs put their common files under one folder called "Common Files".

Answer (score -2):

One think is sure, every app that is placed in common files folder can send info to the owner creator or to the hell if is enabled in task manager startup.

You can make the test.
Install Freemake video converter (not the last version).
Is a program to conver video that dont install services and dont have impact over system speed.
But in "common files" folder also create a folder called "freemake shared" and every time that you start the computer you will see a popup that remember you that need to update the program.
Because send info to creator.